# Grant access to stored procedures and udfs, excluding udfs/procedures which can insert, to a read-only user in the database

Tags: mysql, privileges, sql-grant

I have a scenario where I need to have a read-only user to a database. This user can read tables, as in just view anything. However after executing the below command :

```
GRANT EXECUTE
  ON `randomdatabase`.*
  TO readonlyuser@192.168.16.85;
```

I am able to read any table or view. But when it comes to UDFs and stored procedures, I am not able to execute them. But if I grant `execute` privilege for the user, I get to execute the UDFs and procedures, even those which have the code to insert to a table. So this contradicts to being a read-only user. Is there way to prevent executing specific UDFs and procedures which can insert to a table?

Answer (score 0):

When you grant `EXECUTE` privilege to a routine, execute permission is what the user gets. The permissions do not examine what the content / behavior of the routine is. This allows for you to allow user to modify the content of the database, but only through set of rules defined in the routines.

If you need only to grant read-only access, then you need to exclude those routines that add/delete/update the database.

This behavior is not specific to MySQL, but all other databases work the same way.

Comment: Okay but can I do it like block all inserts for a particular user but grant execute privilege to run UDFs?

Comment: @AravindS You normally do not "block" inserts, but grant only the necessary permissions. In your case SELECT permissions to tables and EXECUTE only on routines that do not modify the data. UDF's (usually done with C/C++), do not need permissions as they work the same way as native functions.